# how can i change ActionMode icon highlight color?

Tags: android, android-actionmode

ActionMode icon highlight color is blue by default, I want to change it to green.
I don't know why google don't have any reference for styling ActionMode in XML, this is ridiculous!

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8640186/2045570

Comment: I don't think so, there's nothing about changing icons highlight color.

Comment: Okay have a look at this one then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13653153/2045570

Comment: Once check this [link][1] one may be you will get solution 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652368/using-a-selector-for-a-menuitem-in-the-actionbar/21422725#21422725

Comment: Once check this [link][1] one may be you will get solution


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652368/using-a-selector-for-a-menuitem-in-the-actionbar/21422725#21422725